# SQl server- writing stored procedure using 'USE [db name]'

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am writing a stored procedure which will compare two similar tables under two different database. Here I am using the keyword **USE [dbname]**.

```
DECLARE 

--INPUT

@BASE_DATABASE_NAME NVARCHAR(50),

@TARGET_DATABASE_NAME NVARCHAR(50),

@TARGET_PRODUCT_ID NVARCHAR(50),

@TARGET_PRODUCT_CODE NVARCHAR(50)

SET @BASE_DATABASE_NAME='USE [DB1]'

SET @TARGET_DATABASE_NAME='USE [DB2]'

SET @TARGET_PRODUCT_ID=4194


SET @TARGET_PRODUCT_CODE = @BASE_DATABASE_NAME ( SELECT PRODUCT_CODE FROM T_PRODUCT_MST WHERE PROD_ID = @TARGET_PRODUCT_ID)

print @TARGET_PRODUCT_CODE.
```

Error--

It's not working...

Can anybody help me out with this? I need to pass the database name dynamically to the sql query.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you please provide the exact error message?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `USE` this way. `USE` sets the database against which all the statements are executed and cannot be used inside another query.

You can use dynamic SQL though to specify your query:

```
DECLARE 

--INPUT

@BASE_DATABASE_NAME NVARCHAR(50),

@TARGET_PRODUCT_ID INT,

@TARGET_PRODUCT_CODE NVARCHAR(50)

SET @BASE_DATABASE_NAME='[DB1]'

SET @TARGET_PRODUCT_ID=1

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT @TARGET_PRODUCT_CODE = PRODUCT_CODE FROM ' 
    + @BASE_DATABASE_NAME 
    + N'..T_PRODUCT_MST WHERE PROD_ID = @TARGET_PRODUCT_ID'

exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@TARGET_PRODUCT_ID INT, @TARGET_PRODUCT_CODE NVARCHAR(50) OUTPUT',
    @TARGET_PRODUCT_ID, @TARGET_PRODUCT_CODE OUTPUT

print @TARGET_PRODUCT_CODE
```

Comment: Thanks Szymon!! It really helping me a lot!! But in my stored procedure I am storing the result into one variable i.e. @TARGET_PRODUCT_CODE which I will use it in other query and your stored procedure didnt stored the result. Please look into it.. Thanks again!!

Comment: I tested that code and it works for me. You need to use `OUTPUT` to return the value of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to Szymon's answer is to use synonyms.  First create your synonyms in the DB:

```
CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[TargetProductCode] FOR [DB2].[dbo].[T_Product_MST]
```

And then your sql syntax becomes:

```
SET @TARGET_PRODUCT_CODE = SELECT PRODUCT_CODE 
FROM dbo.TargetProductCod WHERE PROD_ID = @TARGET_PRODUCT_ID
```

If this doesn't need to be dynamic, this can be a good solution, and can also make for easier testing, if for some reason you need to point a test DB to a different target (can just update the synonym).